# wc_get_product returns empty in woocommerce_new_order hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook, product

I try to get a product object with its ID, to programmatically add a product to the order. Naturally, I use `wc_get_product()`, but it turns out it returns an empty object (despite the product actually exists).
I'm using this function in a function triggered by the hook `woocommerce_new_order`, and I think that's the culprit. In fact, I tried by hardcoding the ID and the result was the same. I also tried the `WC_Product_Factory()`, but the result was the same.

Here is my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'send_new_order', 9999, 3 );
function send_new_order( $order_id, $order )
{
    // some code...

    // get ACF values    
    $bottles_of_the_moment_ids = get_field('bottles_of_the_moment', 'option'); // returns [441,439,444,436]

    foreach ($bottles_of_the_moment_ids as $bottle_of_the_moment_id) {
        $bottle_of_the_moment = wc_get_product($bottle_of_the_moment_id); // returns empty

        $line_items[] = $chosen_bottle_of_the_moment;
    }

    // some code...

    $body = array(
        // order info,
        'line_items' => $line_items,
        // more order info
    );

    // send order to a remote website
    $raw_response = wp_remote_post( $live_url,
        array(
            'headers' => array( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' ),
            'timeout' => 30,
            'body' => json_encode( $body ),
        )
    );
}
```

This same code works when applied to another page hook (`woocommerce_single_product_summary` for example), but not to a process hook (`woocommerce_payment_complete`, `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`, `woocommerce_new_order`...).

Does anyone know how to get product information (that is not in the order) in the `woocommerce_new_order` hook? Why does it return empty?

### EDIT:

The function `wc_get_product()` actually works, the product is correctly retrieved, but weirdly `error_log(json_encode(wc_get_product($id)));` returns empty. I think the problem is solved then...

Comment: Your question is not enough detailed. What is the global context? Why do you need to get that product object there? What are you trying to do? You should do that before, on checkout submit, on order creation, changing/adding data to the order before it's saved to the database.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not used to post on Stack Overflow, I didn't know if I had to detail a lot or not.
Basically, I need to retrieve products entered in an ACF field (in an options page) and add them to my order items. The ACF field returns products IDs (which works well). But I can't retrieve the product object with wc_get_product (it returns empty).
I hope I'm clear enough...